# What is wrong with my sql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'test'(
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `campaincode` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
  `paymentplantype` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
  `contractlength` INT NOT NULL ,
  `monthlyannuityfactor` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `initialfee` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `notificationfee` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `interestratepercentage` INT NOT NULL ,
  `interestfreemonths` INT NOT NULL ,
  `paymentfreemonths` INT NOT NULL ,
  `fromamount` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `toamount` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `timestamp` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `storeid` INT NOT NULL
  )
```

Comment: there is a lot of uppercase!...jks please frovide error message

Comment: See how you used backticks there? Well, there's one place where you used something else!

Comment: Also, it's incredibly unlikely that you want DOUBLE instead of DECIMAL. But what do I know?

Comment: @Strawberry Actually he didn't. Someone edited the answer and put them in there... I tried to revert the edit, but our edits overlapped, so the quotes remained there.

Comment: @joe776 But, in the context of PHPmyadmin, there's nothing else wrong with this query.

Comment: @Strawberry I have no MySQL instance at hand, but would it complain about the unquoted `timestamp` as column name? ... OK, just checked with Postgres and it adds quotes automagically. Maybe MySQL behaves the same, then to quotes really don't make a difference.

Comment: No. There are several common keywords exempted from mysql's list of reserved words. TIMESTAMP is one of them. Although it's still good practice of course to avoid using keywords as table/column identifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sholud remove `'` chars from table name as below

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`campaincode` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`description` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`paymentplantype` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`contractlength` INT NOT NULL ,
`monthlyannuityfactor` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
`initialfee` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
`notificationfee` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
`interestratepercentage` INT NOT NULL ,
`interestfreemonths` INT NOT NULL ,
`paymentfreemonths` INT NOT NULL ,
`fromamount` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
`toamount` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
`timestamp` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`storeid` INT NOT NULL
)
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/ce3df/1/0)

Comment: Yes - and you can remove ALL the backticks too!

Answer (score 0):

Table name has quotes insted it should have backtiks. Try this:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test`(
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
  `campaincode` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
  `paymentplantype` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
  `contractlength` INT NOT NULL ,
  `monthlyannuityfactor` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `initialfee` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `notificationfee` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `interestratepercentage` INT NOT NULL ,
  `interestfreemonths` INT NOT NULL ,
  `paymentfreemonths` INT NOT NULL ,
  `fromamount` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `toamount` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `timestamp` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
  `storeid` INT NOT NULL
  )
```

Some useful information , backticks should always be used. But there are some reasons why a team may prefer not to use them.

Advantages:

- Using them, there are no reserved words or forbidden chars.
- In some cases, you get more descriptive error messages.
- If you avoid bad practices you don't care, but... in real word,
  sometimes they are a decent way to avoid SQL injections.

Disadvantages:

- They are not standard and usually not portable. However, as long as
  you don't use a backtick as part of an identifier (which is the worst
  practice I am able to imagine), you can port your query by
  automatically removing backticks.
- If some of your query come from Access, they may quote table names
  with " (and maybe you can't remove all the " blindly). However,
  mixtures of backticks and double quotes are allowed.
- Some stupid software or function filters your queries, and has
  problems with backticks. However, they are part of ASCII so this
  means that your software/function is very bad.

Please refer: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Answer (score -1):

There are a few problem you are having with your SQL

1. is the way you are checking if the table exists
2. you are not correctly assigning the decimal data type
3. the is no need to wrap
           all the words in '

below is the code to check if the table exists if i dont exists create it

```
/* CHECK IF THE TABLE EXISTS IN sys.objects*/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Table]') AND type in (N'U'))


BEGIN  -- If it dont create the table 
    CREATE TABLE [VI].[dbo].[Table] 
        (
             id INT NOT NULL identity(1,1) PRIMARY KEY 
             , campaincode VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL 
             , [description] VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL --if you want to use keywords that SQL uses like description it is best practise to wrap them in []
             , paymentplantype VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL 
             , contractlength INT NOT NULL 
             , monthlyannuityfactor decimal(18, 0) NOT NULL -- when using decimal you must also type in the amount of numbers you want before the .(decimal place) and the amount you want after the decimal place 
                                                            -- i have set this to 18 before the . and 0 after this is the deafult when creating tables
             , initialfee decimal(18, 0) NOT NULL 
             , notificationfee decimal(18, 0) NOT NULL 
             , interestratepercentage INT NOT NULL 
             , interestfreemonths INT NOT NULL 
             , paymentfreemonths INT NOT NULL 
             , fromamount decimal(18, 0) NOT NULL 
             , toamount decimal(18, 0) NOT NULL 
             , [timestamp] INT NOT NULL 
             , storeid INT NOT NULL 
         )
END
```

if you need any more help message me also don't forget to mark the answer as complete if it answers your question

Comment: What's wrong with `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/create-table.html

Comment: The tags referenced phpmyadmin, in the context of which this answer is inappropriate!